# How to check Maven command is finished running

Tags: maven

As title, any sign to known when Maven process `mvn clean test` is finished running? or any trick to do that?

Currently, I run maven command on the Windows Command Line, when maven is finished running, it close this window.

Many thanks,

Edit 1: My current solution is adding new line `echo Done > status.log` into my **.bat** file

```
cd /d "E:\AutoTest\Java\workspace\AngularProject"
mvn clean test > "E:\AutoTest\Java\workspace\AngularProject\maven.log"
echo Done > status.log
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question/problem. If you run maven in command line, can't you just see how the process is running straight away?

Comment: I've resolved my issue by adding new line `echo Done > status.log` in my .bat file

`cd /d "E:\AutoTest\Java\workspace\AngularProject"
mvn clean test > "E:\AutoTest\Java\workspace\AngularProject\maven.log"`

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and post an answer describing how you solved your problem. This might help someone else in the future.